# Issue with displaying data with React and Flask

Tags: python, pandas, reactjs, flask

I am working on a data science project with Flask, Pandas and React. I am currently working on a React component that will display a form and then when submit is entered the data will be displayed. Everything almost works except the displaying of the data. Here is my code:

React Component:

```
  var Warwounded = React.createClass({
  getInitialState(){
      return {check: true}
  },
  change(){
      this.setState({check: false})
  },
  renderForm(){
      return (
    <div className='numbersArea'>
        <h3>Looking at the wounded</h3>
        <p>Please enter a number and the data returned will be the wars
        which have that number and higher</p>
        <form method='POST' action='/index'>
            <input name='number' type='NUMBER'/>
            <input type='submit' onClick={this.change}/>
        </form>

    </div>
    )
  },
  results(){
      return(
          <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
          </div>
      )
  },
  render: function(){
    if(this.state.check){
        return this.renderForm()
    }else{
        return this.results()
    }
  }
})
```

Python side of the Code:

```
#This function will bring the user to the index page.
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    #This line will ensure that the user is logged in.
    if 'username' not in session:
      return redirect(url_for('login'))
    name = session['username']
    if request.method == 'POST':
       data = Data()
       number_entered = int(request.form['number'])
       wars = data.wounded(number_entered)
       print(wars)
     return render_template('index.html', title='Login Page', name = name)
```

I have spent the last 2 hours working on this and I know that for the most part the python side of my code is working. (The print(wars) line gives me exactly what I want.) At this point, I believe that my problem is more on the React side since I am just starting out with it. I also know that when the form is submitted and the following line is called:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

it will eventually render the index.html file 'resetting' everything. Thus, I believe that the answer is with React possibly with a function / process I still do not know. Thank you for any help provided!!

Comment: You do not show the captured value in `<input name='number' type='NUMBER'/>`. I expect to see something like `<input name='number' type='NUMBER' value={this.props.number} />`.  You should consider to use redux-form (http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/) which does a lot of low level stuff for u.

Comment: I will check redux-form out and see what it can do-it may be the missing piece!

Comment: I guess there is a bit of   overhead and learning curve involved to integrate redux-form into your project, but you don't need to reinvent the wheel! There is a redux-form forum on discord and you probably can get faster feedback for simple questions there https://discord.gg/29AY7

Comment: Thank you again Anthony! I will check discord out and see what I can get there. Thank you again!